# How to integrate Dedicated worker in winjs

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

### How to integrate Dedicated worker in winjs..

i am working on a winJS application.My application start with downloading images.How can i integrate Dedicated Worker in my application..?

Answer (score 0):

good to familiarize yourself with WinJS.Promise which is used for asynchronous tasks within javascript based windows store applications. check `WinJS.xhr()` api. if the images can be accessed at an url, you can simple bind src attribute of the img tag to the url.

```
<img data-win-bind="src: imageUrl" />
```

Comment: hi sushil...My requirement is, first of all listview load with local data from DB then call the webservice and i need to add that data to existing listview.But it take more time.So i need to start pararel download when the application start.

Comment: Is there any possible way to set alt image like alt text in winJS .

Comment: your comment is not very clear. assuming that your local data from db does not have image and hence, you are looking for alt image - your view model need to return placeholder image url something like ms-appx:///images/placeholder.png that can be added to your vs project. once the webservice call completes - update the view model property imageUrl to point to the real url. this need to be used along with the data binding for img.src like mentioned earlier. for webservice call - look into `WinJS.xhr()`

Comment: How to highlight the first item of winJS listview?